# Has anyone found a way to force a status bar style in SwiftUI 2?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI 1 it was possible to use a custom UIHostingController to return the desired status bar style in the preferredStatusBarStyle override. This is no longer possible in SwiftUI 2 as you do not specify the hosting controller directly. Has anyone found a way to control the status bar style (for the entire application is fine) in SwiftUI 2?

Comment: In my opinion it’s not a workable solution for a production app. It replaces the default SwiftUI UIHostingController (not sure of full impact), it recreates the entire View graph twice, and it flashes the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation (and a solution using a UIViewController wrapped in a UIViewControllerRepresentable), I decided to try adding .preferredColorScheme(.dark) to the topmost ContentView. Oddly, this worked, and correctly set the status bar to match. Of course, it also changes the rest of the app to match, but in my case this was an acceptable solution. The nice thing is it doesn't require any messing around with UIKit.